# Looping through parameters of a function in bash, how to check for condition on the ordinal number of the parameter?

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop

I have a function in bash that takes in arguments and I want to extract all the arguments Except the first one.

I'm trying this

```
alias save=save
save(){
    for i in "$@"; do 
        if [ i -gt 1 ]
        then
            echo $i
        fi
    done
}
```

but it's giving the error

> sh.exe": [: i: integer expression expected

I know `$i` is the argument itself, so doing this

```
if [ $i -gt 1 ]
```

gives the error

> $ save hi hola
>   sh.exe": [: hi: integer expression expected
>   sh.exe": [: hola: integer expression expected

If `$i` is the argument itself, and `i` doesn't work as a variable, how else would this work?

Comment: `if [ $i -gt 1 ]` ... that is, `$i` instead of just `i`.

Comment: @fedorqui `$i` is the argument itself. it gives error (check update)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do it in Bash is `"${@:2}"` which makes multi-element expansion start at the 2nd argument. This makes use of `shift` not necessary. You still may be able to access the first argument if needed.

```
save() {
    for i in "${@:2}"; do 
        echo "$i"
    done
}
```

Also an easier method if you just want to print the arguments line by line is to use `printf`:

```
save() {
    printf '%s\n' "${@:2}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a shift first to get rid of the first arg. That way you don't need the condition in the body of the loop, and you can also simplify `for i in "$@"` as `for i;`, like this:

```
save() {
    shift
    for i; do 
        echo $i
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately is is not possible to use index with arguments array `$@` or `$*` ,  you will get a  bad substitution error

But you can assign it to another array and use index on it like this

```
 declare -a ARRAY=("$@")
 for ((i=1; i< ${#ARRAY[@]};i++ )) ; do
        echo "${ARRAY[$i]}"
 done
```

Note that you have the index in `$i`